# How can I get a complete SO ads page?

Tags: support, advertising

I am interested in an ad I saw on Stack Overflow, but I didn't catch its URL. It might have been an open source project, or some great product for programmers; all I know is that it showed up randomly and had a great icon.

Is there a place where I can see all the ads that have recently run on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two forms of ads on Stack Overflow:

1. commercial, paid ads
2. free, open source, community ads

The current **free open source community ads** can be browsed here:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads

Archives of older ads are at

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source-advertising

As for the **commercial paid ads**, we don't *yet* have a way to browse those, but we are looking at it...