# Is there a page with a list of all the advertisements placed on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, advertising

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revisit ad in Stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14442/how-to-revisit-ad-in-stackoverflow)
>   [How can I get a completed SOF ads page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102639/how-can-i-get-a-completed-sof-ads-page)

There was an advertisement on the RHS ad pane that caught my eye just as I clicked on a question link. Upon hitting the back button the ad pane had rotated onto the next random(?) ad  placement, and despite refreshing and navigating the site I've not seen that ad again.

Is there a page containing a list of all the non-Stack Exchange/Careers ads that are presently running on Stack Overflow?

Comment: actually, here's a better one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102639/how-can-i-get-a-completed-sof-ads-page?rq=1

Comment: @JoshCaswell thanks Josh. Turns out the ad was a community open source one, so WIN! :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Is there an auto-downvote for dupes now?

Comment: @JoshCaswell no, unless some build was deployed that changed it overnight..